# Qual é a ordem de execução de um construtor em classe herdada?

Tags: c#, .net, orientação-a-objetos, herança, construtor

Quando fazemos um construtor assim:

```
Classe(int x, string y) : base(x) { ... }
```

o C# executará o construtor base que `Classe` derivou. Mas quem executa primeiro, o meu novo construtor ou o construtor da classe usada como base?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Eu imagino que entenda que construtores são método estáticos, por isso eles não são herdados. Mas sempre que existe uma hierarquia todos os construtores precisam ser executados. Em C# sempre tem por que no mínimo um tipo é herdado de `Object`.

O compilador chama pelo menos o construtor padrão das classes acima se nada for chamado, não precisa chamar explicitamente, com `base()` ou não. De qualquer forma existe uma ordem para executar.

O que pode parecer estranho é que antes de mais nada os membros do tipo são todos inicializados com um valor padrão para depois chamar os construtores, o que obviamente é ineficiente.

A ordem de execução dos construtores é sempre da base para a derivada. Se tiver vários níveis, começa do primeiro nível, ou seja, sempre começa pelo `Object`, e depois vai executando a hierarquia até chegar no tipo que está sendo invocado de fato.

O objetivo é começar fazer primeiro o mais geral para depois fazer o mais específico, até porque o mais específico pode "desfazer" o que o geral fez.

Para testar pode fazer isto:

```
using static System.Console;

public static class Program {
    public static void Main(string[] args) => new Derivada(1, "");
}

public class Inicial {
    public Inicial() => WriteLine("Inicial"); //chamará base(), especificamente Object()
}

public class Base : Inicial {
    public Base(int x) : base() => WriteLine("Base");
}

public class Derivada : Base {
    public Derivada(int x, string y) : base(x) => WriteLine("Derivada");
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/1ectvA). E [no **.NET Fiddle**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/nRy0s6). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Class/OrderConstructor.cs).

Outro ponto importante é que o `base()` sempre executa antes do corpo do método construtor. Você não deveria chamar o construtor dentro do corpo, a não ser que tenha um motivo muito forte para fazê-lo, e mesmo assim deve escolher fazer um ou outro.

E também precisa notar que o construtor estático executa antes de tudo em algum momento da execução da aplicação, pode ser logo no início dela, pode ser logo antes da chamada da primeira instância, ou outros momentos.

Imagino entender que `base` é uma palavra-chave da linguagem representando o construtor genérico da classe anterior.

Se tiver um `this()` que é a forma de chamar um outro construtor na mesma classe, primeiro o `this()` é chamado. Se tiver vários encadeados, vai na ordem inversa, assim como é feito com o `base()`.

Em outras linguagens isso pode variar.